# how to run progress dialog until a condition is true?

Tags: android

Is there any way to run a progress dialog until a condition is true while checking in a while loop? something like this..

```
progressdialog.show();
while(some condition)
{

//progress dialog running not freezed
}
progressdialog.dismiss();
```

edit:
all in one thread
no asynctask to be used..

Comment: It's not a good practice to have such loops on main thread. Have You tried to use AsyncTask? It will resolve issue with UI freezing.

Comment: i don't want to use asynctask

Comment: Then I would recommend to check-out that one before deciding not to use Threads in android: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html and http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html . Last one describes exactly your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workload will have to go into a different thread - otherwise the progress indicator's animation will not work. So the easiest way is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and showing the progress dialog in `onPreExecute()` and dismissing it in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: You _have_ to use an AsyncTask. If you do your work in the UI thread, the UI thread cannot animate the progress indicator.